# One Exchange 2010 issue

Tags: exchange-2010

When end user use the outlook anywhere to connect company exchange 2010 server from outside, it will come out the Synchronization Log:

**15:18:26 Microsoft Exchange offline address book

15:18:26 Not downloading Offline address book files.  A server (URL) could not be located.

15:18:26 0X8004010F**

Can help me to resolve this issue. I have tried many methods but can not resolve it!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the OAB virtual directory for external users. You do that by running the following command (with the proper url. Probably your OWA url):

> Get-OABVirtualDirectory | Set-OABVirtualDirectory -InternalURL https://exchange.domain.local/OAB -ExternalURL https://mail.domain.com/OAB

Comment: Hi, I can confirm my externalURL is right. But it still will come out the same error. Any other suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Try to hit the external URL from a web browser from outside your office. You will likely get an error page. Let us know which error page you're getting.

Comment: Hi ,it will come out one page and ask me to key in the user name and password! After typing in, it will come out the below msg:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.